# how to use audioplayers package to play local audio flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test, audio-player

I want to use the `audio players` package to run audio `files` on my app,

 NOTE:

- I use local files in `assets` file like this

```
assets\audio\he_has_got_the_packa.mp3
```

this path file

I try to use `AssetSource`

```
// this is an object from AudioPlayer
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
...

TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
       player.setSource(AssetSource('assets\audio\he_has_got_the_packa.mp3'));
    },
       child: Text('to play click here'),
   ),
```

but isn't running because `asynchronous suspension` 
I try searching but I don't get content to this thing

Answer (score 2):

you use below code and you issue is fix.

```
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                player.setSource(AssetSource('sample-15s.mp3')).then((value) {
                  player.play(AssetSource('sample-15s.mp3'));
                });
              },
              child: Text('to play click here'),
            ),
```

also please verify this image also.

[image]

Happy Codeing....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
       await player.play(AssetSource('assets\audio\he_has_got_the_packa.mp3'));
    },
       child: Text('to play click here'),
   ),
```

Adding `await` keyboard and making `onPressed()` `async` is important.